# Come tradurre la parola "feature" in italiano?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-request, single-words, foreign-words

Da tanto tempo sto cercando di tradurre la parola "feature" in italiano. La parola più vicina è "caratteristica", ma questa potrebbe indicare qualsiasi tipo di comportamento del software, inclusi rompicapo o semplicemente modi di interagire a livello più basso i quali dettagli possono non essere di alcuna rilevanza per l'utente.

Invece "feature" si riferisce ad una caratteristica interattiva positiva di valore per l'utente finale.

Come si può aggirare questo problema di apparente mancanza di parola sostitutiva adeguata in italiano?

Comment: Potrebbe andare [_peculiarità_](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/peculiarita/), inteso come qualità singolare, derivato da [peculiare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/peculiare/) cioè Singolare, particolare, proprio di una determinata cosa?

Comment: Perché non banalmente "funzionalità"? Di solito è tradotto così e non mi sembra ci siano sfumature di significato differenti.

Comment: ...o anche semplicemente “funzione”, senza eccedere in sillabe non necessarie (cf. “tipologia/tipo”, “modalità/modo” etc.).

Comment: Interessante @DaG, non ci avrei mai pensato. Ho sempre usato la parola funzione con il significato di function, ovvero funzione matematica. Grazie mille, se vuoi puoi anche tu contribuire una risposta tra le altre.

Comment: @JoselinJocklingson: Ormai avrai visto che [“funzione”](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/funzione) ha molti altri significati, oltre a quello matematico.

Answer (score 8):

Potrebbe tradursi come "funzionalità", perchè ha una accezione più positiva.

> Il mio software ha queste features: ...
>
> Il mio software ha le seguenti funzionalità: ...

Comment: Benvenuto su ItalianSE!

Answer (score 3):

Un termine che potrebbe andare bene nel tuo contesto potrebbe essere *[peculiarità](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/peculiarita/)*, inteso come qualità singolare, derivato da [peculiare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/peculiare/) cioè:

> **peculiare** agg. [dal lat. peculiaris, der. di peculium «sostanze, proprietà»]. – 1. Singolare, particolare, proprio di una determinata
>   cosa o persona (o di un insieme di cose o persone)

Come fa giustamente notare @OldManofAran si potrebbe utilizzare anche il termine funzionalità, non essendoci particolari sfumature di significato differenti.